# Setting an ASP Label control with text from JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm new to JQuery and I'm writing code to check a registration form.  Here's my label in the server page:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelErrorFirstName" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
```

and my JQuery script:

```
if(firstnameTxt.length == '') {
      $('#<%= LabelErrorFirstName.ClientID %>').text("Please enter a first name.");

  }
```

I access this script from the OnClientClick event in a button on the form which I know works i.e. I set alerts here which shows it's getting there.  I've commented out the 'if' statement in case that was the problem but it isn't.

What I want to happen is to have this label's text property set if the first name textbox is empty to "Please enter.." etc. I've tried many variations but I can't get it.

What am I missing?

Paul

Comment: Did you tried a `RequiredFieldValidator` control?

Answer (score 1):

Length is an integer not a string.

```
if(firstnameTxt.length == 0) {
    $('#<%= LabelErrorFirstName.ClientID %>').text("Please enter a first name.");
}
```

Also, make sure your label is being found by jquery:

```
if( $("#<%= LabelErrorFirstName.ClientID %>").length > 0 ) {
}
```

Comment: Yes, length does return an integer but, as I said in my post, "I've commented out the 'if' statement in case that was the problem but it isn't."